# How to delete saved data from shared preferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Today, I would like to seek your help regarding an issue I have in my acitvity, I am putting three strings in shared preferences using StringTokenizer.Everything is fine, now I would like to remove each textview from parent view and as well as from shared preferences using its long click event .

Here is my code for your reference.

```
 This is the place where  I am storing the bitmap and other two string names in shared preferences

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

            StringBuilder strCont = new StringBuilder();
            screenOnePreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsActivity.this);
            String savedStringCont = screenOnePreferences.getString("appName1", "");
            StringTokenizer stCont = new StringTokenizer(savedStringCont, ",");
            String[] savedListCont = new String[stCont.countTokens()];
            for (int j = 0; j < savedListCont.length; j++) {
                savedListCont[j] =stCont.nextToken()+",";
                strCont.append(savedListCont[j]);
            }
            StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
            screenOnePreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsActivity.this);
            String savedString1 = screenOnePreferences.getString("appPackName1", "");
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(savedString1, ",");
            String[] savedList1 = new String[st1.countTokens()];
            for (int j = 0; j < savedList1.length; j++) {
                savedList1[j] =st1.nextToken()+",";
                str1.append(savedList1[j]);
            }
            StringBuilder strImg = new StringBuilder();
            screenOnePreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsActivity.this);
            String savedImage = screenOnePreferences.getString("appImage1", "");
            StringTokenizer stimg = new StringTokenizer(savedImage, ",");
            String[] savedListImg = new String[stimg.countTokens()];
            for (int j = 0; j < savedListImg.length; j++) {
                savedListImg[j] =stimg.nextToken()+",";
                strImg.append(savedListImg[j]);
            }
            strCont.append(clickedAppName);
            str1.append(clickedApp);
            strImg.append(Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT));
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsActivity.this).edit().putString("appName1",strCont.toString()).commit();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsActivity.this).edit().putString("appPackName1",str1.toString()).commit();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsActivity.this).edit().putString("appImage1",strImg.toString()).commit();
```

---

This is the place where I am retrieving the same and binding to dynamic textviews.

```
String[] array;
static SharedPreferences prefsCont;
static  String[] savedList2;
static List<String> list;
static StringBuilder strCont;
static String savedStringCont;
static String  savedString2;
static String savedStringImg;
static   StringTokenizer stCont;
static StringTokenizer st2;
static  StringTokenizer stImage;
static  String[] savedListCont;
static   String[] savedListImage;
static  List<String> numberList;
static Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
static  int numOfContacts;




    strCont  = new StringBuilder();
    prefsCont = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    savedStringCont = prefsCont.getString("appName1", "");
    savedString2 = prefsCont.getString("appPackName1", "") ;
    savedStringImg = prefsCont.getString("appImage1", "");
    stCont = new StringTokenizer(savedStringCont, ",");
    st2 = new StringTokenizer(savedString2, ",");
    stImage = new StringTokenizer(savedStringImg, ",");
    savedListCont = new String[stCont.countTokens()];
    savedListImage = new String[stImage.countTokens()];
    savedList2 = new String[st2.countTokens()];

    numberList = Arrays.asList(stCont.toString().split(","));
    int prevTextViewId = 0;
    numOfContacts = stCont.countTokens();
    for ( int K = 0; K < numOfContacts; K++) {
        final int listenerI = K;
        savedListCont[K] = stCont.nextToken();
        savedList2[K] = st2.nextToken();
        savedListImage[K] = stImage.nextToken();


        byte[] b = Base64.decode(savedListImage[K], Base64.DEFAULT);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), yourSelectedImage);


        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            if(savedListCont[K] != null && savedList2[listenerI] != null && yourSelectedImage != null ){
                final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setText(savedListCont[K]);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, bd, null, null);
                textView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                textView.setMaxLines(1);
                textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MIDDLE);
                int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
                textView.setId(curTextViewId);

                final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId);
                textView.setLayoutParams(params);
                 textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                     //   Here I would like to delete individual textview from shared preferences.

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;

                ll.addView(textView, params);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this it help you ................

**keyname** is value which you want to **delete**........

`prefsCont.edit().remove("KeyName").commit();`

in your case example :-`prefsCont.edit().remove("appName1").commit();`

and if you want to **delete all** then use this `prefsCont.edit().clear().commit();`

use this to find out value which is you clicked ....

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, "your textview value");
```

and use this to put array into the SharePrefernce

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
prefsCont.putStringSet("key", set).commit();
```

enjoy coding ...............

Comment: Hi Sishildlh, Thank you for your quick help, Actually, the solution provided by you removing every textview, but actually I want to remove only selected textview on long click of selected textview.

Comment: I want to remove individual string tokens from shared preferences Sushildlh, .

Comment: Which individual string tokens you want to remove .?

Comment: Okay, let me put in this way, my real scenario is,I will long click a textview in gridview in Activity B and pass  it to Activity A via shared preferences , so on long clicking every textview from Activity B , those textview will sit in my Activity A, so I want to remove individual textviews adding in Activity A on long click, savedListCont[K] this variable has all strings.

Comment: I am spliting received string appName using string tokenizer sushildlh.

Comment: you can use `ListArray<String> str`  and add all your data inside it. after adding just remove value which you clicked `str.remove("your textView value")` and add remaining str value put into the sharePrefernce .

Comment: Sure Sishildlh, let me give a trail. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112275/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-adithya).

Answer (score 0):

To remove specific values use below

```
--> SharedPreferences.Editor.remove() followed by a commit()
```

To remove all data then use below

```
--> SharedPreferences.Editor.clear() followed by a commit()
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, as posted below for Sishildlh solution,  Actually, the solution provided by you and him will removing every textview, but actually I want to remove only selected textview on long click of selected textview

Answer (score 0):

you can use,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
```

if you want to remove particular value from shared preferences use below,

```
preferences.edit().remove("key").commit();
```

if you want to remove all data,

```
preferences.edit().clear().commit();
```